# Grand Central Dispatch Growing Memory

Tags: swift, cocoa, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch

Overview:  I'm creating a Swift program that downloads live JSON Data that updates very frequently (possibly several times per second) and then displaying that to the user in a tableView.  When the program begins it does the downloading in a separate thread using GCD, essentially running the thread the whole time the program is running.

Problem: The program downloads and displays the data nicely but I notice that the program's memory (as seen in Xcode debug navigator) keeps growing much faster than the JSON data is coming in.  Within a few minutes it's a couple of hundred MBs.

I call dispatch_async from my 'Coordinator' object which also stores the collection of instance vars i'm updating.  Here is my code

```
func startDownload() {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
      while (true) {
         self.myDataPipe.downloadMarketOdds(self.marketsToUpdate)
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.referenceToViewController!.reloadUpComingMarketsTableView()
            self.referenceToViewController!.reloadMainTableView()
        })
      }
   } ) // end of dispatch_async

   // end of start()
}
```

I'm new to GCD and have done some searching on stackoverflow but haven't found anything that has been helpful yet.  Could someone please point me in the right direction or point out something obvious i'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to analize memory report from Xcode or get more detailed information via Instruments.

I would sugget you to use autorelease pool (to force release of all autoreleased objects):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
      while (true) {
        autoreleasepool {
             self.myDataPipe.downloadMarketOdds(self.marketsToUpdate)
             dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.referenceToViewController!.reloadUpComingMarketsTableView()
                self.referenceToViewController!.reloadMainTableView()
            })
        }
      }
   } )
```

Or download data by GCD timer:

```
let interval = 5.0 // seconds
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)
let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10)
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, {
    self.myDataPipe.downloadMarketOdds(self.marketsToUpdate)
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.referenceToViewController!.reloadUpComingMarketsTableView()
        self.referenceToViewController!.reloadMainTableView()
    })
})
dispatch_resume(timer)
```

Comment: Thanks sgl0v I used the autoreleasepool and it worked as suggested.  Much appreciated :)